# TypeScript asking to add type to key value

Tags: angular, typescript

I've got form in my angular project. And this form contains input with image upload. So I use FormData to send the data to server. I try to use function to append form fields to FormData.

```
export function toFormData<T>(formValue: T) {
    const formData = new FormData();

    for (const key of Object.keys(formValue)) {
        const value = formValue[key];  <--- error here
        formData.append(key, value);
    }

    return formData;
}

sendForm() {
    const team = toFormData(this.form.value);
    this.teamService.sendTeam(team).subscribe(() => {});
}
```

I've got an error from ts-lint "Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'unknown'. No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'unknown'". IDE underlines formValue[key] expression. Try to add types, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`formValue[key]` is `any` because `T` doesn't narrow types, that's fine.

To suppress this error you need to cast `any` to `unknown` like that `T extends Record<string, unknown>`. Now it means `value` has unknown type and it should be asserted first before usage of the variable.

```js
export function toFormData<T extends Record<string, unknown>>(formValue: T) {
    const formData = new FormData();

    for (const key of Object.keys(formValue)) {
        const value = formValue[key];
        // feel free to remove Blob if it's not your case.
        if (typeof value !== 'string' && !(value instanceof Blob)) {
            continue;
        }
        formData.append(key, value);
    }

    return formData;
}
```

Comment: What error do you get there? you can try to narrow `T`, if you don't expect any other type there `<T extends object>`. I've updated the answer also with replacement of `any` to `unknown`.

Comment: Done, now it should work for you even without key cast issue.